# SQL Server 2008 table with data as parameter for UDF

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, user-defined-functions, table-valued-parameters

**My question:** Is it possible in SQL Server 2008 to define temporal table in stored procedure and pass it as variable to user defined function?

I need to do the following:

1. I have procedure `dbo.GetMsgCntData`.
2. This procedure is making some calculations and as a result of this procedure I have data into temporary table that is defined in this procedure (`GetMsgCntData`):

   ```
   -- table defined in dbo.GetMsgCntData
   DECLARE @tmpTable TABLE (
       ID BIGINT,
       FirstName VARCHAR(50),
       LastName VARCHAR(50),
       UserType varchar(50),
       SenderID bigint,
       IsArchive bit
   )
   ```
3. So, `@tmpTable` contains some data.
   I need to run user defined function `GetCnt(@status, @MsgTempTable)`, but I need `getCnt` function to access `@tmpTable` data. Basically I need something like this:

   ```
   -- to be written at the end of dbo.GetMsgCntData
   SELECT cnt(*) total,
       dbo.GetCnt('open', @tmpTable) as opened,
       dbo.GetCnt('closed', @tmpTable) as closed
   FROM @tmpTable
   -- where @tmpTable is temporal table
   ```
4. I tried to define `@table` in `GetCnt` as user defined type.

   ```
   CREATE TYPE dbo.tmp_Messages AS TABLE (
       ID BIGINT,
       FirstName VARCHAR(50),
       LastName VARCHAR(50),
       UserType varchar(50),
       SenderID bigint,
       IsArchive bit
   )

   CREATE FUNCTION FUNCTION [dbo].[GetCnt] (
       @Status nvarchar(10),
       @MsgTempTable dbo.tmp_Messages READONLY
   )
   ....
   ```

but this gives me error message:

```
Operand type clash: table is incompatible with tmp_Messages
```

I think that my idea is simply incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Temporary table is not compatible with user-defined type.
 You should declare your temporary table as user-defined type:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.tmp_Messages AS TABLE 
(
 ID BIGINT,
 FirstName VARCHAR(50),
 LastName VARCHAR(50),
 UserType varchar(50),
 SenderID bigint,
 IsArchive bit
 )
 GO
 --function declaration 

        CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetCnt] (
            @Status nvarchar(10),
            @MsgTempTable dbo.tmp_Messages READONLY
        )...
        -- table defined in dbo.GetMsgCntData
        DECLARE @tmpTable dbo.tmp_Messages;
        INSERT INTO @tmpTable(---some actions

SELECT cnt(*) total,
    dbo.GetCnt('open', @tmpTable) as opened,
    dbo.GetCnt('closed', @tmpTable) as closed
FROM @tmpTable
```

Please read a good article about table-valued parameters: [http://beyondrelational.com](http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/77/posts/11288/table-valued-parameters-to-a-table-valued-function-underappreciated-features-of-microsoft-sql-server.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can use user defined table types to achieve this. Try this

```
CREATE TYPE T1Type
AS TABLE (ID BIGINT,
    FirstName VARCHAR(50),
    LastName VARCHAR(50),
    UserType varchar(50),
    SenderID bigint,
    IsArchive bit
)
```

In your SP

```
DECLARE @tmpTable T1Type
INSERT INTO @tmpTable
SELECT * FROm TableName
```

In your function

```
CREATE FUNCTION FUNCTION [dbo].[GetCnt] (
    @Status nvarchar(10),
    @MsgTempTable T1Type READONLY
)
```